# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`

Tags: json, vb.net

I know there's already a bunch of these questions on SO but none of those answers is working for me. I've been on it all day now and I'm just fried so it's an easy win for the JSON people out there.

The error is

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FrozenSmoke.WorkflowDescription]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Path 'Workflows', line 1, position 13.
```

The code is (VB.NET)

```
Dim z As New List(Of WorkflowDescription)
z = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of WorkflowDescription))(ResponseStatus.Content)
```

Here is the JSON I'm getting back from the server and is contained in ResponseStatus.Content

```
{"Workflows":[{"GUID":"594d2946-7bee-49b3-b8bf-e5ee6715a188","Name":"ProcessElectronicContribution"},{"GUID":"fe368a11-2b79-41f9-bee9-edb031612365","Name":"AddActivist"},{"GUID":"4c552492-0014-439d-952b-aeb320e6d218","Name":"AddPartialActivist"}]}
```

Here is the class

```
Public Class WorkflowDescription
Public Property Name As String = ""
Public Property GUID As String = ""
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is not simply an array/list but an object container which contains a `Workflows` property which is a list/array.

> {"Workflows":[{"GUID": ....

Workflows is the List/Array but note that it is inside a brace.  That is the "outer container".

```
Public Class WorkFlowContainer
    Public Property WorkFlows As List(Of WorkflowItem)
End Class

Public Class WorkflowItem
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property GUID As String
End Class
```

The `WorkFlows` element in the json will map to the property of the same name.  You can get rid of the container after you deserialize:

```
' ultimate destination
Private myWorkFlows As List(Of WorkflowItem)
...
' elsewhere
Dim jstr = ... ` from whereever

' deserialize to the container
Dim wf = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of WorkFlowContainer)(jstr)
' extract the list 
myWorkFlows = wf.WorkFlows
```

You can ignore the WorkFlowContainer with an extra step in deseriazlizing:

```
Dim jstr = ... ` from whereever
Dim jopbj - JObject.Parse(jstr)

myWorkFlows = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of WorkFlows))(jobj("Workflows"))
```

This way you dont have to define the extra class and dont have to use `wf.` to get at the data.

---

You probably know that most arrays can be deserialized as either a `List` or array.  To define `Workflows` as a property array:

```
Public Property WorkFlows As WorkflowItem()
```

Comment: My situation was really weird.  I had a IEnumerable<string> return that worked on one dev-machine....moved code to another dev-machine with same version of VS (2012)...and got this error.  Go figure.